# Xcode - how to reset glitched Xcode 10.2 installation?

Tags: xcode10.2

I'm updating to Xcode 10.2, and have a glitched installation stuck at about 77%. It has been sitting like that for over 30 minutes. Restart did not help - the installation gets stuck again.

**How to fix glitched/stuck Xcode 10.2 installation process?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a clean uninstall of everything related to Xcode.

Recommend first saving the noted folders (ending in "/") or files as they contain the customizations you have for Xcode:

1. ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets/
2. ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes/
3. ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/KeyBindings/
4. ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/
5. ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
6. ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/

And then completely removing all of the Xcode 10 sprawl, delete the following folder (ending in "/") or file as noted:

1. /Applications/Xcode.app
2. ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
3. ~/Library/Developer/
4. ~/Library/MobileDevice/
5. ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
6. /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
7. /System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeExtensionSupport.bom
8. /System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeExtensionSupport.plist
9. /System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeSystemResources.bom
10. /System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeSystemResources.plist

Then installing Xcode again. If successful, hand-copy your modifications back.  Always good to maintain a manual backup of the mods... just in case. ;-)

Comment: I ended up doing $ sudo rm -rf /Applications/Xcode.app , followed by a reboot. This seems to have re-downloaded a fresh version of XCode. I will see if more cleanup is necesary