# Broken xib with xcode 10.3

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10.3

Unable to view or manipulate all xib file after updating xocde to 10.3 version.
 Is there any solution for that?

My OS version: 10.14.4 (18E226)

> Delete Derived data[Not working]

[image]

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57159637/4219574 Mac restart is no needed.

Comment: If nothing helps and 10.3 is a huge blocker try downloading the old xcode version

Comment: https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.2.1/Xcode_10.2.1.xip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Completely delete your derived data from preferences and later restart your machine.

Comment: Thanks but  delete your derived data is not working and  restart your machine is already answered by @Tehdrew https://stackoverflow.com/a/57159876/6630644

Comment: Had the same problem and this solution worked for me

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Xcode Preferences -> Location -> Derived data.
2. Close Xcode.
3. Delete Derived data.
4. Relaunch the Xcode and try to open the Xib.

[image]

UPDATE:- Finally I got the problem. In my case, it was an IBDesignable Class with IBInspectable Properties. I was assigned this class to my view. To fix this I just create a subclass of my IBDesignable class.

Comment: It seems you also have to restart your computer.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem after these install problems:

1. App Store upgrade of Xcode stalled (similar to [Xcode - how to reset glitched Xcode 10.2 installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55560596/xcode-how-to-reset-glitched-xcode-10-2-installation))
2. Safe mode reboot stalled
3. Downloaded 10.3 from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
4. New Xcode had no Simulators installed -- OK, fix that

After all that waiting, an opened project looks like this

[image]

The above described remove-DerivedData-restart fixed this. OK, that's *post hoc* reasoning, ymmv.

Comment: Having done this, *somebody* (App Store app) thinks the installation is still going, and tried overnight to re-install. (But Xcode was, atypically for me, left running.) How do I stop this?

Answer (score 2):

Restarting the computer fixed the problem. At least for me.